# How to override or replace an imported function call on a different module

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am leveraging an existing framework for a tool build activity based on python. Let me get into my issue straight :

Let's say the framework I am using is  having a module named **m1.py** where I am having below function

```
    def func_should_not_run(*args,**kwargs):
        <doing something >
```

And I have a another module named **m2.py** where I am having below class :

```
    from m1 import 
    class JustAClass:
        def __init__(self,*args,*kwargs):
            <All kind of initialisation..>
        def run_something(self,*args,*kwargs):
            <lots of code before>
            func_should_not_run(*args,*kwargs)
            <lots of code after>
```

Now my code module **my_mod.py** is having below class where I am creating an instance of above class from framework and calling **m2.JustAClass.run_something** inside another method as below

```
    class JustAnotherClass:
        def __init__(self,*args,*kwargs):
            <All kind of initialisation..>
            self.obj1=JustAClass(*some_args,**some_kwargs)
        def run(self):
            <some code before>
            self.obj1.run_something(*some_other_args,**some_other_kwargs)
            <some code after>
```

Now due to some implementation issue with m1.func_should_not_run which is getting called inside m2.JustAClass.run_something , **I need to replace it with my own function func_should_run so that when func_should_not_run will be called inside m2.JustAClass.run_something, it should instead execute func_should_run from my module.**

How can I achieve this?

Is there any way if I can override the import statement "from m1 import" on m2.py from  my_mod.py?

Comment: Technically you can do this with `mock.patch`, but that will be an incredibly difficult solution to maintain.

Answer (score 1):

This solution is risky for some aspects and could potentially fail given its side-effects, but worth to be mentioned in my opinion.

The idea is to replace (or better reload) the module that depends on the module you want to change, after some adjustment. I am going to start from the code and then I will show you the problems and limits of this approach:

```
from m2 import JustAClass

def func_should_run():
    print('This is the function you want to call')

class JustAnotherClass:
    def __init__(self,*args, **kwargs):
        self.obj1 = JustAClass(*args, **kwargs)
    def run(self):
        self.obj1.run_something()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import importlib
    
    importlib.import_module('m1').func_should_not_run = func_should_run
    importlib.reload(importlib.import_module('m2'))
    janc = JustAnotherClass()
    janc.run()
```

Output:

```
This is the function you want to call
```

After importing `importlib`:

1. `importlib.import_module('m1').func_should_not_run = func_should_run`: I am importing module `m1` and changing the `func_should_not_run` reference to `func_should_run`. This means that, **for all the following calls to `func_should_not_run`**, the code executed is the one of `func_should_run`. Obviously, this is also not valid for objects referencing the old `func_should_not_run`, like `m2.JustAClass`, so
2. `importlib.reload(importlib.import_module('m2'))`: here I am reloading the module `m2`, that is going to use the new version of `func_should_not_run` because the module `m1` is already loaded in the cache (i.e. `sys.module`) and therefore is not going to reload it (for this reason *Transitive reloading* can't occur, unless you explicitly do that).
3. From now on, every instance of `JustAnotherClass` correctly calls `func_should_run`

---

#### Should you use `importlib.reload()` for this?

Typically, reloading a module is useful when you have applied changes to a certain module and you do not want to restart the whole system to see those changes. In your case, unless you have clear in mind all the risks of this approach, you are kind of abusing the `reload()`.

---

#### What are the main side-effects of this solution?

For start, reloading has its costs, especially if inside the module you have some initialization code that you do not want to re-execute. This means:

- You are inevitably going to execute the module code twice (at least)
- Be sure to comment your code explaining that every occurence of `func_should_not_run` is actually replace with `func_should_run`, but this is definitely not a good practice and not maintainable if used in many places.

---

To conclude, it is a simple as much as risky solution that can be adopted taking all the necessary precautions, with the awareness that it is just a hack and not a reasonable design decision.

Comment: This hack actually helps for temporary purpose. But as you also said , this is not a good idea from a design perspective. So I am currently redesigning some components to avoid this

Comment: But really thanks for your detailed explanation

Comment: If possible, redesigning is definitely your best choice.